# how to create an instance of a class to access through the application

Tags: java

i have a util `class` where which don't have access to session object. i want to initialize this util class only once while `login` and want to get that instance throughout  application.

Here every user need to have his own instance of that util class how to achieve this.

please help me

Comment: Pass any required information to it during login, put it into session (or application) context; it's not clear if it's per-user or per-application. I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: The proper solution depends on the environment. Is it a standalone app, a Java EE app?

Comment: it's a java EE application.  @DaveNewton - it's per user not per application

Comment: @user1815754 Can you please post the whole context of the application? There are plenty of options you can use but to recommend one, we need to know what you're dealing with and what are you restricted to.

Comment: my util class only accept the amount value, it will calculate the amount based on user(user information need to stored in that util class while login into the application) same as to all other user new instance of utill class needed

Comment: Please explain the issue: you can pass whatever you want into a class, and put whatever you want into the session.

Comment: Looks like a global `Map<String, UserInfo>` with some eviction policy (maybe based on session timeout events) should do the job, even though it's against all rules.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ??

```
private static MyClass instance;
private MyClass(){}

    public static MyClass getInstance() { 
        if (instance != null) {
            return instance; 
        } else {
            return new MyClass();
        }
    }

    public static void setInstance(MyClass inst) {
        instance = inst;
    }
```

Comment: if i create a singleton only one instance will be available to all user here i want a different instances to different users by initializing while each user login into the application

Comment: @user1815754 wouldnt your users be in different sessions ??

Comment: I have never use them, but maybe the solution is on session tracking.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlow yes they would in different session, for different sessions i want different instance for that util class

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Then you can pass parameters to the factory method and return a new instance for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GanGnaMStYleOverFlow about singleton, but want to provide better version of its implementation:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass instance;
    private MyClass() {}

    public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() { 
        if (instance != null) {
            instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

This class cannot be instantiated directly because constructor is private. You cannot create 2 instances of this class because it is managed by `getInstance()`. This implementation is threadsafe because `getInstance()` is `synchronized`.

Comment: but i dont want the singleton pattern.

Comment: my util class only accept the amount value, it will calculate the amount based on user(user information need to stored in that util class while login into the application) same as to all other user new instance of utill class needed